# Trying to sort by count of association in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a User model and a PullRequest model - a user has many PullRequests and a PullRequest belongs to User. I have a counter column for keeping track of the total number of PullRequests a user has - but I want to be able to find how many a user has after a specified date. I do this using:

```
  has_many :pull_requests_as_creator_sprint, -> {where("merged_at >= ?", "2015-10-22")}, class_name:'PullRequest', foreign_key: 'creator_id', dependent: :destroy
```

but how can I use this to sort my data in the pull request controller?

Currently I have `@team_members = User.order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction, 'pull_requests_created_count DESC').includes(:pull_requests_as_merger_sprint, :pull_requests_as_creator_sprint)`

which displays by total created count - but I'd like to order by created by since

```
  has_many :pull_requests_as_creator, class_name:'PullRequest', foreign_key: 'creator_id', dependent: :destroy
  has_many :pull_requests_as_creator_sprint, -> {where("merged_at >= ?", "2015-10-22")}, class_name:'PullRequest', foreign_key: 'creator_id', dependent: :destroy
  has_many :pull_requests_as_merger, class_name:'PullRequest', foreign_key: 'merger_id', dependent: :destroy
  has_many :pull_requests_as_merger_sprint, -> {where("merged_at >= ?", "2015-10-22")}, class_name:'PullRequest', foreign_key: 'merger_id', dependent: :destroy
```

Is my user model - The :pull_requests_as_creator/merger relations are fine, they just use a counter cache. But I want to be able to also sort my data by pull_requests since a date.

```
  belongs_to :creator, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :merger, class_name: 'User'
```

Is my user model.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
User.select('users.id, count(pull_requests.id) AS pull_requests_count').joins(:pull_requests).where('pull_requests.created_at >= ?', your_date_here).group('users.id').order('pull_requests_count')
```

You can make it a scope, so u can have easier acces to it.

```
User.select('users.id, count(pull_requests.id) AS pull_requests_count').joins(:pull_requests_as_merger).where('pull_requests.created_at >= ?', your_date_here).group('users.id').order('pull_requests_count')
```

or

```
User.select('users.id, count(pull_requests.id) AS pull_requests_count').joins(:pull_requests_as_merger).where('pull_requests_as_merger.created_at >= ?', your_date_here).group('users.id').order('pull_requests_count')
```

Comment: My association is actually pull_requests_as_creator - (I have merger also) - and not just pull_requests. When I tried to update this to take that into account it didn't work .. any ideas?

Comment: And what exacly happens? It throws out an error, or returns a wrong result?

Comment: It errors on missing table - I've never used joins before so I think I changed too many things and somethings should be table name and some should be association? 

To clarify:

My table is pull_requests - my associations are user has many pull_requests_as_creator and user has_many pull_requests_as_merger

Comment: I'm a little confused now. Can you provide me your models, what have you used, and full error you get?

Comment: Sorry - I've updated the post - I think what you're suggesting is going to work, I just cant seem to implement it :/

Comment: Sorry for long time. I've had to think about it. I think you should use your association name as an argument for joins, and the rest should be like I typed. If this won't work, try renaming it also in the where()

I've edited my answer with possible solutions.